# Php script error with on click event

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress as my cms and I am devloping a voting system. I want this code to run only on click event but it runs on every page load

How can i only make it run on click even

```
<script>
function addvote(){
 alert("<?PHP hello(); ?>");
}
 < /script>

 <?PHP
FUNCTION hello(){
   $postid="79";
   $current_votes = get_post_meta($postid, "votes", true);
$new_votes = intval($current_votes) - 1;
update_post_meta($postid, "votes", $new_votes);
$return = $new_votes>1 ? $new_votes." votes" : $new_votes." vote";
echo $return;
 }

?>

<button onclick="addvote()">Vote Now</button>
```

Comment: do you want to `addvote()` run on each click or `hello()` function? `hello()` function will run on each page request

Comment: i only want it to run on click event

Comment: need to explain what you expect your code to do...in detail, and behavior you want. php and javascript run in completely different environments

Comment: I only expect the code to run on click event 
But instead the code runs on page request .. mean runs on each page load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot invoke PHP from JavaScript like that. You need AJAX: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax

Also, use unobtrusive JavaScript - attach event handlers in your Script code, not in the HTML. Basic example how to implement what you probably want, using jQuery:

```
// In your HTML page:
<scipt type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $.get("/hello.php", function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

// In hello.php:
<?php
function hello() {
    // ...
    echo $return;
}

hello();
?>
```

You need to understand the distinction between server- and client-side processing. All your PHP code is executed on the server on each page request. The results are then sent to your browser, which displays them. Now there can be JavaScript code in your page, which is executed by the browser after the page is loaded. In order to invoke PHP code on a button click (or similar), this client-side code needs to make a new HTTP request to the server - this is what AJAX is for. This new request will trigger the execution of another PHP script. The results are transferred back to the JavaScript function after it finishes, and can then be used to do something, like adding additional content to your page.

Comment: can i put in my themes functions.php
i mean that function hello
putting it in theme funcions.php
will give it gloabal acces at my site

Comment: I have no experience with WordPress, so sorry - I don't know.

Comment: returning value of 0 
using url there $.get("wp-content/themes/9GAG/hello.php"

Answer (score 0):

when you request this page PHP parser will encounter with `hello()` function, and it will run it and therefore it will print the return value of `hello()` function in the javascript `alert()` function, so the output wil be, (assuming return value be 1):

```
<script>
    alert('1');
</script>
```

as @lethal-guitar mentioned you need to call the `hello()` function with an AJAX request.